# Adding multiple rows with ajax in datatables using dataType:text

Tags: javascript, datatables

I've a strange problem adding more than ONE row with ajax in datatables.

This is my table init:

```
 var table= $('#table').DataTable( {

    bFilter: false,
    responsive: true,
    paging: false,
    "pageLength": -1,
    "info": false,
    scrollCollapse: false,
    scrollY: false,
    "ordering": false
});
```

This is my button to add row retrieved from ajax (see dataType: text):

```
   $("body").on("click","#btn-add", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var table= $('#table').DataTable();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        dataType:"text", // <-- I use plain text cause the reals rows have got a lot of input select and this way is more simple than others
        url: "ajax/get-rows.php",
        data: { }, //omitted parameters, not usefull for the example
        success: function(data) {

            table.rows.add($(data)).draw( false );

        }
    });

   });
```

This is my get-rows.php

```
<?php
//START
?>
<tr>
  <td>COL 1</td>
  <td>COL 2</td>
  <td>COL 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>COL 1</td>
  <td>COL 2</td>
  <td>COL 3</td>
</tr>
<?php //END ?>
```

I always get this error:
table id=table- Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 1, column 0

But if I modify get-rows.php to only ONE row it works!

```
<?php
//START
?>
<tr>
  <td>COL 1</td>
  <td>COL 2</td>
  <td>COL 3</td>
</tr>
<?php //END ?>
```

What's the problem?

Comment: What is the data returned by php?

Comment: I use only echoed text. See my get-rows.php

Comment: I was talking about ajax/get-rows.php

Comment: Yes i understand. I print plain text outside php tags like: <?php ?>I PRINT THIS<?php ?>

Comment: I guess you better return JSON and also check the columns you are sending back

Comment: No i need to use plain text for my purpose

Comment: please check https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html